# Formatting Framed - some FrameStyle graphic directives don't work?

Tags: output-formatting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.04 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0.**

---

The FrameStyle option in Framed seems to work for some graphics directives but not others, eg:

```
Framed["yo", FrameStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

But

```
Framed["??", FrameStyle -> Thickness[0.1]]
```

and

```
Framed["??", FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.1]]]
```

seem to have no effect (having varied thickness parameter)

[image]

Comment: I can only confirm that this happens on my PC (Win7-64/MMA8.04) too. The documentation suggests that the above should be possible, though not a single example using `Framed`, `FrameStyle` and `Thickness` together is given.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It indeed seems that the thickness of the frame doesn't respond to any of the options in `Frame`. As a workaround, you *could* do this (**although I would recommend the second approach below, instead!**):

```
SetOptions[FrameBox, BoxFrame -> 3]; 
Framed["AA", FrameStyle -> Red]
```

However, the `SetOptions` will affect **all** frames drawn in your notebook (even ones that have been drawn before).

A more customizable approach would be to use the lower level `FrameBox` directly. This is shown here - using the ability of `BoxFrame` to specify thicknesses of all sides individually:

```
FrameBox["AA", FrameStyle -> Red, 
  BoxFrame -> {{1, 4}, {1, 1}}] // DisplayForm
```

[image: framed]

**Edit**: I neglected to add the comment by Mike Honeychurch, according to which it's also possible to get the above output with this line:

```
Framed["AA", BoxFrame -> {{1, 4}, {1, 1}}, FrameStyle -> Red]
```

However, the `BoxFrame` option appears in red because it's not an officially documented option (and therefore this last line may stop working in future versions).

But: This `Framed["AA", "BoxFrame" -> {{1, 4}, {1, 1}}, FrameStyle -> Red]` does not make `"BoxFrame"` red neither in the Front End nor in Workbench.

Comment: `BoxFrame` can be used directly with `Framed`, so use of lower level boxes can be avoided: `Framed["AA", BoxFrame -> {{1, 4}, {1, 1}}, FrameStyle -> Red]`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thanks - but I get the red syntax error highlighting, even though it does indeed produce the desired result. I personally would prefer to avoid the red highlighting because it's distracting.

Comment: I've found this sort of syntax highlighting occasionally when doing things that work but are not documented. If it is distracting you can always change the colour. ;)

Comment: @Rolf Mertig Thanks for the edit. Now if only it could also be done with something like `f=Function[Null,##]`...

Comment: Hmm `BoxFrame -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` doesn't seem to work on 10.3 Windows. `BoxFrame -> 3` is ok though.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, same on Mac. So the warning about this not being an official option has to be reiterated... I'll just add that it did work for *Mathematica* version 8, in case anyone still uses that (I do quite often).