# FrameStyle in Inset with Framed expression

Tags: graphics, boxes

I am creating some plots that use `FrameStyle->AbsoluteThickness@5` and `PlotStyle->AbsoluteThickness@0.5`. In my plots' `Epilog` option, I want to use some `Inset[Framed@...,FrameStyle->AbsoluteThickness@0.5]` expressions. Upon exporting the graphics to PDF, I noticed that the `FrameStyle` option does nothing. This lead me to the following question on this site:

[Formatting `Framed` - Some `FrameStyle` graphics directives don't work](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8943/formatting-framed-some-framestyle-graphic-directives-dont-work)

So I tried the following, to get a feeling for what `BoxFrame` does:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@0.5,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@0.5,
 ImageSize -> 180,
 Epilog -> {Inset[
    Framed["sin(x)", BoxFrame -> {{0.1, 0.5}, {5, 0}}],
    {3/2 Pi, 0.5}]}]
```

The resulting PDF looks like this:

[image]

It seems like only integer numbers work in the `BoxFrame` option. But how can I make the frame thinner? Especially, how can I make it exactly 0.5 pt thick?

Comment: I used to make nested `Framed` objects to take control.

Comment: Could you provide an example of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible way would be using an **inline** `Cell` with specified `CellFrame`.

```
labelcell =
    Cell[BoxData[
                 ToBoxes[
                        Style[ Defer[Sin[x]],
                               20, GrayLevel[.4], FontFamily -> "Constantia"],
                        TraditionalForm]
                ],
         CellFrame -> {{1, 4}, {6, 10}},
         CellFrameMargins -> 5,
         CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[0.2, 0.4, 0.7]
        ] // Cell[TextData[{#}]] &; (* make it an inline Cell *)

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
     PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@0.5,
     Frame -> True,
     FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@0.5,
     ImageSize -> 500,
     Epilog -> {
                Inset[RawBoxes[labelcell], {3/2 Pi, 0.5}]
               }
    ]
```

[image: CellFramed label]

Comment: Thanks! With your solution I finally get the desired output, even in the PDF. It's a shame that there seems to be no simple way for such a simple problem...

Comment: @einbandi Thanks for acceptance! I don't know why `Framed` doesn't work.. Fortunately there are always more than one roads lead to Rome. :D

Answer (score 2):

I hate situations when *MMA* is forcing me to create such inelegant solutions. It is how I am dealing with it:

The basic idea is to govern the margins by `outerFrame` `FrameMargins`. One good thing here is `FrameMargins`:

> specifies the **absolute** margins in **printer's points** to leave inside the frame

```
With[{
  outerFrame = Sequence[Alignment -> Center, Background -> Black, 
                        FrameMargins -> {{25, 5}, {10, -1}}],
  innerFrame = Sequence[Background -> White, FrameStyle -> None, ImageMargins -> 0]
   },
 Plot[
  Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@0.5, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@0.5, 
  ImageSize -> 480, Epilog -> {
    Inset[
     Framed[Framed["sin(x)", innerFrame], outerFrame]
     , {3/2 Pi, 0.5}]}]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: I like the idea of this answer, but I just can't get it to work properly. The thinnest frame I can get is exactly as thick as the one using `FrameStyle` or `BoxFrame` (which looks like 1 pt in the resulting PDF).