# Pretty InputField

Tags: gui-construction, inputfield

I'm trying to create a "template" notebook for myself.
I want to get input from a single `InputField`, and then run a few operations on it.

**How can I make the `InputFiled` (that is, the box itself) be prettier?**

How can I manipulate it's style?

**EDIT:**
I was asked to define prettier (which stands to reason).
So let's have [*WolframAlpha's*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) (website) input box as a refrence point.

Comment: Define "prettier". `With[{img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Elaine"}]},
 Panel@Column[{img, InputField[]}]
 ]` :)

Comment: Ahhh... Lenna...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get custom colors and rounded corners by adding a custom frame to a frameless `InputField`. The following code approximates the look of Wolfram Alpha's input field:

```
With[{opts = {FrameMargins -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0}},
    Framed[
        Framed[InputField[, ImageSize -> {500, 25}, Appearance -> "Frameless"], 
            FrameStyle -> Red, RoundingRadius -> 5, opts
        ],
        BoxFrame -> 3, RoundingRadius -> 7, FrameStyle -> Lighter@Orange, opts
    ]
]
```

[image]

Note that due to a bug, the `FrameStyle` option for `Framed` does not follow thickness directives (and possibly others), so a lower level [workaround using `BoxFrame`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8949/5) is necessary.

Comment: Wow! Excellent solution! This would really make my "template" notebook so much prettier. Thanks.