# Control of individual Framed edges?

Tags: graphics, front-end, display

Is there an option or method for `Framed` analogous to `Frame` in `Graphics` to control display of individual edges, eg bottom, left, top, right?

`Framed` is useful for visualizing nested structures, but often 4 sides are redundant, eg in this healthcare related prototype would like to display only the left edges:

If not an option, is there a workaround that does *not* explicitly involve `Graphics`?

[image]

Comment: In version 8, it used to be possible to do something like this, [see this question and answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8943/245). Unfortunately, it no longer works in version 10.

Comment: Related: [(21082)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21082/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would a `CellFrame` around a `TextCell` work?

```
Framed[
 x -> TextCell[
   Column[{"Depression", "PTSD", "Diabetes Type II", "Smoker"}], 
   "Text",
   CellFrame -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great, is it possible to control line width?

Comment: @alancalvitti Harder than I thought, given that `CellFrameStyle` shows up in the option inspector: ``System`CellFrameStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[12], None}, {None, None}}`` yields [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9DlO9.png).  Note that (on V10.4.1) `CellFrameStyle` is not already in the ``System` `` context and ``Global`CellFrameStyle`` won't work. -- Just checked and `"CellFrameStyle" -> {{AbsoluteThickness[12], None}, {None, None}}` also works.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative way of getting a similar display would be to define a new function `leftFramed` that only puts a vertical extensible line to the left of the content:

```
leftFrame /: MakeBoxes[leftFrame[obj_], _] := 
 RowBox[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", ToBoxes[obj]}]

Framed[x -> 
  leftFrame[
   Column[{"Depression", "PTSD", "Diabetes Type II", "Smoker"}]]]
```

[image: bracket]

You can see that this vertical line is in fact an extensible character, not a graphical line.

In the same vein, you could also use other extensible symbols to decorate the left side:

```
leftBrace /: MakeBoxes[leftBrace[obj_], _] := 
 StyleBox[RowBox[{"{", ToBoxes[obj]}], SpanMaxSize -> Infinity]

Framed[x -> 
  leftBrace[
   Column[{"Depression", "PTSD", "Diabetes Type II", "Smoker"}]]]
```

[image: brace]

Comment: Jens, yours is a nice approach too, I will likely use it as well, but accepted Michael E2 because `TextCell` seems easier more user friendly.